# Rationalize irrational equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals, radical-equations

$$
\begin{cases}
\sigma_{1,(2)}=x_1+x_2\\
\sigma_{2,(2)}=x_1x_2\\
\end{cases}\\
\color{red}{  
\begin{align*}  
&&p_2&=\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}\\   
&\Rightarrow&\left({p_2}^2-\sigma_{1,(2)}\right)^2&=4\sigma_{2,(3)}\\  
\end{align*}}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\sigma_{1,(3)}=x_1+x_2+x_3\\
\sigma_{2,(3)}=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3\\
\sigma_{3,(3)}=x_1x_2x_3
\end{cases}\\
\color{red}{  
\begin{align*}  
&&p_3&=\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3}\\   
&\Rightarrow&\left[\left({p_3}^2-\sigma_{1,(3)}\right)^2-4\sigma_{2,(3)}\right]^2&=64{p_3}^2\sigma_{3,(3)}\\  
\end{align*}}
$$
What about the situation of more variables?

> How to rationalize it 
>   $$p_4=\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3}+\sqrt{x_4}$$

I have ran it above through *Wolfram Mathematica* and no result return.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rationalising" the expression?

Comment: @TheoBendit Conversion to polynomial equation with symmetric polynomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> \begin{gather*}
> &256\sigma_{4,(4)}\left(3p^4-2p^2\sigma_{1,(4)}-{\sigma_{1,(4)}}^2+4\sigma_{2,(4)}\right)^2\\
> \\
> {\large=}\!\!&\left(\left(\left(p^2-\sigma_{1,(4)}\right)^2-4\sigma_{2,(4)}\right)^2-64p^2\sigma_{3,(4)}+64\sigma_{4,(4)}\right)^2\\
> \end{gather*}

\begin{cases}
\sigma_{1,(4)}=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\\
\sigma_{2,(4)}=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4\\
\sigma_{3,(4)}=x_1x_2x_3+x_2x_3x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_1x_2x_4\\
\sigma_{4,(4)}=x_1x_2x_3x_4\\
\end{cases}
\begin{gather*}
p=\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3}+\sqrt{x_4}
\end{gather*}